# Excel: INDEX( ,MATCH( ), )) combination works with ranges but not data formatted as TABLE

Tags: microsoft-excel

**The set-up:**

I have two Excel sheets with data, both "Formatted as table(s)". One is a large data set, with many rows and columns (fields) and the other is sort of a "dictionary", with just 2 rows and 2 columns (fields).

**Table1** *(data set)*

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
| month | week | productName | price     | sold pcs. |
+---------------------------------------------------+|
| jan   | 1    | heavy       | (formula) | 25        |
| jan   | 2    | heavy       | (formula) | 51        |
| jan   | 3    | heavy       | (formula) | 06        |
| jan   | 4    | heavy       | (formula) | 00        |
| jan   | 1    | light       | (formula) | 39        |
| jan   | 2    | light       | (formula) | 11        |
| jan   | 3    | light       | (formula) | 98        |
```

**Table2** *(dict)*

```
+---------------------+
| productName | price |
+---------------------+
|  heavy      | 125   |
|  light      | 65    |
```

**What I need to do:**

What I need to do is bring the values (*product prices*) from the dictionary into the large data set, where certain values (*product names*) match.

**What I tried:**

```
=INDEX(Table2[@price], MATCH(Table1[@productName], Table2[@productName], 0))
```

When working with ranges, this combination works excellently. However, when I do it like this, with data formatted as tables, it only matches in the first row, of Table1.

**This is the result I get**:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
| month | week | productName | price  | sold pcs. |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| jan   | 1    | heavy       | 125    |  25       |
| jan   | 2    | heavy       | #N/A   |  51       |
| jan   | 3    | heavy       | #VALUE |  06       |
| jan   | 4    | heavy       | #VALUE |  00       |
| jan   | 1    | light       | #VALUE |  39       |
| jan   | 2    | light       | #VALUE |  11       |
| jan   | 3    | light       | #VALUE |  98       |
```

First row is properly matched, the second row (again the same as first) is not found, and from there error values start. What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misusing the named ranges:

- `Table2[@productName]` points to a single element in the table
- `Table2[productName]` points to the whole column
- `Table2` points to all the columns and lines of the table, headers excluded

You can do it easily with a VLOOKUP:

```
=INDEX(Table2,MATCH([@productName],Table2[productName],0),MATCH("price",Table2[#Headers],0))
```

Alternative solutions:

```
=VLOOKUP([@productName],Table2,2,0)

=VLOOKUP([@productName],Table2,MATCH("price",Table2[#Headers]),0)
```

Or, provided each productName is unique, you can use SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF(Table2[productName],[@productName],Table2[price])
```

Comment: This works excellently! I did not realise that I was not using the "selectors" properly (*single @element* vs. *whole field* vs. *#headers*). Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
=INDEX(Table2[[#All],[Price]],MATCH([@productName],Table2[[#All],[ProductName]],0),1)
```

Note. the use of #ALL, this selects the whole column, not just a ROW.